# How can I control functions to execute in order?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am newbie in Javascript. I am trying to manage couple of function in order. But when it gets to API calls it dosen't wait for response and go backs to continue its execution and makes my code messy. This is a sample:

```
function readFacebook()
{
    var myID = getMyID();
    console.log("myID=  " + myID);
}

function getMyID(){
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log("response.id= "+response.id);
        return(response.id);
    }); 

}
```

The output is completely strange. First

```
console.log("myID=  " + myID);
```

show output and then

```
console.log("response.id= "+response.id);
```

will be called. Anyone can explain how I can force it to implement in order. I meant program should wait until response from facebook instead of working asynchronously!

**EDIT**

I actually call 3 time API from main function to three sub functions. How can I organise this:

```
function getMyID(){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log("response.id= "+response.id);
            return(response.id);
        }); 

    }

function readFacebookEvent(id)
{
    var myID = getMyID();
    console.log("myID=  " + myID);
    FB.api('/me/events', function(response) {

        for(i=0; i<response.data.length;i++) {
            var str;
            var eventID = response.data[i].id;
            getEvent(eventID,myID);
        }
    });
}

function getEvent(eventID,myID){

        FB.api("/"+ eventID , function (response3) {

            if (response3 && !response3.error) {
                //console.log(response3);
                var date = new Date((response3.start_time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," "));
                var diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000);
                //console.log(diff);
                if(myID == response3.owner.id && diff < 0 )
                {
                        //console.log("found=  " + myID);
                        var t = getImage(eventID);
                        if(t)
                        {
                            console.log("TRUE");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("false");
                        }
                }

            }
        });
  }

function getImage(eventID){
    //console.log("******eventID== "+eventID);
    FB.api("/"+eventID+"/picture",
            {
                "redirect": false,
                "type": "normal"
            },function (response2) {
              if (response2 && !response2.error) {
                  str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response2.data.url+"'/>";
                  //console.log("response2.data.url=  "+response2.data.url);

                  //str +="<b>name: </b>"+response3.name+"<br>";
                  document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML+=str;
                  return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;   
                }
            }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned the call to facebook's api is **asynchronous** meaning that you cannot be certain to know when the resulting data will come back from your request. You can work around and guarantee the order you're looking for by using a callback:

```
function readFacebook(id) {
  console.log("myID=  " + id);
}

function getMyID(cb) {
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log("response.id= "+response.id);
    cb(response.id);
  }); 
}

getMyID(readFacebook);
```

What's happening here is that the call to FB.api accepts a callback that fires when the response comes back from the server. Since we're supplying our own callback to getMyID, we can use that to get access to `response.id` once the server responds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I must study call back from basic. What about if I have 2 or 3 functions inside?

Comment: You can certainly nest multiple callbacks, but that can get illegible quickly. I recommend taking a look into Promises and how they work. Here is an exceptional video guide to them: [Javascript promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OU7WuVGSuZw)

Comment: you don't really need to nest callbacks, you can name them and use the names inside of each other, passing any pertinent arguments when you invoke it. basically, don't use anons as callbacks and use DI-style arguments instead of closures... you can also use the callbacks themselves as objects to hold extra properties (instead of globals).

Comment: @dandavis can you show it for above example or any simple example to make it clear?

Comment: @Bernard: sure, above using bind(): http://pagedemos.com/8ngseykm5afq/1 , and above using hard-coded (but un-nested) callbacks: http://pagedemos.com/8ngseykm5afq/2 . Now, promises do have a lot of advantages, especially the library-based ones, and i'm not dissing promises, i'm just saying callbacks need not be nested...